# Pycharm bad path to interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have problem with new created project with PyCharm community 2019.3.

After creating new enviroment with fresh python 3.7 interpreter, the interpreter path in terminal is still related do the linux system path:

```
(venv) *@*:~/PycharmProjects/test$ python
import sys
sys.executable

--> /usr/bin/python3.7
```

instead of:

```
/home/*/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python
```

but if i check the interpreter path in Pycharm python console then i get proper result.

In project settings Project interpreter path is:

```
Python3.7 (test) ~/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python
```

PATH for this interpreter are:

```
/home/*/PycharmProjects/test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/usr/bin/python3.7
```

After creating new venv with python 3.7 and after activate it, problem remains:

```
echo $PATH
/home/*/PycharmProjects/test/venv2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

PATH is ok `/home/*/PycharmProjects/test/venv2/bin` but interpreter is from `/usr/bin/python3.7`.

**Question** How to correct this issue?

On JetBrains [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006972760-PyCharm-wrong-terminal-interpreter)

Comment: Did you restart the application?

Comment: if you type `which python` in terminal, can you see  the path ?

Comment: @Raymond which python --> proper path.

Comment: @a_guest i restarted application several times, recreated, created new one --> problem remains

Comment: as far as I understand - the virtual environment in the `test/venv` is set of executables. The terminal does not know anything about the `venv` until you've overridden the default `PATH` (this should be done with `source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate` ) see this https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/

Comment: @MarekSchwarz after deactivate venv and reactivate in project venv --> source ./venv/bin/activate --> problem remains

Comment: This was done in the same shell session? The activation is valid only for current shell. After the activation you should get - `which python` -> the venv one. Then running this `python` should give you the `venv python`. If this is not true then I don't know what is going on.

Comment: @MarekSchwarz yes all done in same shell session. `witch python` give bad result pointing to the linux default python alias

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Can you verify `ls /home/*/PycharmProjects/test/venv2/bin/python` exists? I suggest you submit an issue at [jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) directly.

Comment: @a_guest it exist: ls --> `activate      activate.fish     easy_install      pip   pip3.7  python3    python-config
activate.csh  activate_this.py  easy_install-3.7  pip3  python  python3.7  wheel`. Question created on jetbrains.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Could you please share the issue id?

Comment: @a_guest added at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Pycharm v2019.3 Terminal PATH is bugged. The issue is not occur in previous versions.